# PHP variable with multi conditions expression

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

I am going through a website's code and I came across this line:

`$useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());`

What does it mean?

Comment: is a boolean expression .. the result is true or false depending the boolend result  of the  different  part of the expression in this case if the 3 part of the expression are true the result is true otherwise is false

Comment: What exactly are you confused by here?

Comment: @scaisEdge So if all those conditions are true `$useStaticLoader` will be `true`, otherwise it will be `false`, right?

Comment: exactly  .. i have update the first comment for this

Comment: yes it checks for php versions and the zend loader file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a boolean expression as `scaisEdge` said on his comment, to make it clear to you let's examine that expression :

First the variable `$useStaticLoader` will hold the result of the expression which can be `true` or `false` that's clear so far .

The first part of the condition is checking weather the current PHP version is greater or equal 5.6

- `PHP_VERSION_ID` is a [predefined constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) that returns the
  version id of PHP for 5.6 it returns something like **50630** in php 7 something like **70025**.

The second part of the condition is checking weather the engine used to execute PHP code is [ZEND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Engine) or [HHVM](https://hhvm.com/).

The last condition is checking weather the `zend_loader_file_encoded` function exists which is a part of the [Zend Guard loaded extenion](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-5/zend-server.htm#zend_guard_loader_-_php_api.htm) which means he is checking weather the [Zend Guard loaded extenion](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-5/zend-server.htm#zend_guard_loader_-_php_api.htm) is installed or not.

To Simplify it the condition is checking if the the PHP version is greater than or equals 5.6 and if it is not HHVM and if the Zend Guard loaded extension is not available or installed.